# Angular 11 > 12 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have just upgraded my angular app from Angular 11 to 12 using the steps provided from https://update.angular.io/. I am able to compile and run. However, when I run `npm test`, I got the following error for all my test:

```
> npm run env -s && ng test

⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...13 08 2021 17:49:51.294:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9880/
13 08 2021 17:49:51.334:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.4 server started at http://localhost:9880/
13 08 2021 17:49:51.334:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited
13 08 2021 17:49:51.337:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
13 08 2021 17:50:22.921:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9880/
13 08 2021 17:50:22.999:INFO [Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Mac OS 11.0.0)]: Connected on socket xsFemeP1G85n7QySAAAB with id 91698738

...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
        at extractCommentsWithHash (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:9555:1)
        at ShadowCss.shimCssText (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:9118:1)
        at node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:22336:1
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at compileStyles (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:22335:1)
        at compileComponentFromMetadata (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:21882:1)
        at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileComponentFromMeta (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:22492:1)
        at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileComponent (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:22482:1)
        at Function.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:27388:1)
        at getComponentDef (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:1108:1)
```

Below are my current configurations:

1. Extracted package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.0.3",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.6",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001088",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.1",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-tableau": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.10.3",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.2",
    "@ngneat/spectator": "^8.0.3",
    "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "cypress": "^4.9.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.2.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^4.1.1",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "latest",
    "htmlhint": "^0.15.1",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.4",
    "husky": "^3.1.0",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jest-mock": "^24.9.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "ng-mocks": "^12.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "puppeteer": "^5.3.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.7.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^4.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  },
```

2. karma.conf

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      captureConsole: Boolean(process.env.KARMA_ENABLE_CONSOLE),
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: path.join(__dirname, './reports/junit/'),
      outputFile: 'TESTS-xunit.xml',
      useBrowserName: false,
      suite: '', // Will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: path.join(__dirname, './reports/coverage'),
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
      ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    // Level of logging, can be: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'],
      },
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

3. tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance if anyone is able to help.

Comment: could you try to remove package-lock and try again? `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i`

Comment: Hi @eko, I have tried your suggestion but seems to get the same error message

Answer (score 27):

I have managed to troubleshoot and solve the issue. I have also a `tsconfig.spec.json`, which extends from `tsconfig.json`. This `tsconfig.spec.json` overrides the module property from `es2020` to `commonjs`. As such, by removing the override property, my tests are running again. Hope this helps anyone who faced the same issue as me.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: I don't know how many times I checked my tsconfigs, but I always overlooked and ignored this override. Thanks! You have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Glad my answer helps!

Comment: I'm getting the same problems after an upgrade and unfortunately I don't see any module override on tsconfig.spec.json. Is there a way to regenerate all of these files after an upgrade?

Comment: It turns out my main tsconfig file was using commonjs, I changed it to 2020 and that resolved this problem. I then also had to add `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: This fixed it for me too, thanks.  What pointed to this as being the problem?

Comment: my `tsconfig.spec.json` looks lie below:
`{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "files": ["test.ts", "polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]
}`