# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

Tags: angular, npm, angular12, angular13

I have upgraded my Angular application from 12 to 13 version. And I started getting this error during unit test run.

```
Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.61 (Windows 10) AppComponent should create the app FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
            at extractCommentsWithHash (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:9130:18)
            at ShadowCss.shimCssText (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:8694:34)
            at map (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:22402:26)
            at Array.map (<anonymous>)
            at compileStyles (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:22401:19)
            at compileComponentFromMetadata (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:21948:13)
            at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileComponentFromMeta (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:22570:21)
            at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileComponent (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2020/compiler.mjs:22560:21)
            at Function.get (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:24583:47)
            at getComponentDef (http:###/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:1119:16)
        Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
```

I tried this solution but it didn't work.

```
manually remove package-lock.json
manually remove folder node_modules
npm install
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Is it connected to Angular version upgrade?

Comment: did you removed node_modules completely after removing package-lock and reinstalling all modules with npm install? what do you mean by "manually remove bin folder in node_modules"? you should remove the whole node_modules, not anything inside it.

Comment: @AliDemirci, I updated the question, I removed the node_modules folder as well and called npm install. But it didn't help.

Comment: are you sure that you're also updated package versions of angular on package.json?

Comment: I have noticed that I didn't upgrade @angular/cdk and @angular/material. I fixed it, reinstalled dependencies and still get the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68797111/3387259

I have changed `commonjs` to `es2020` in `tsconfig.json` and also added `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to tsolve the issue by setting in my tsconfig.json "target": "es2020",
tsconfig.app.json "module": "es2020", tsconfig.spec.json "module": "es2020".

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using a config.env and forgot to put "ATLAS_URI=" before my connection url. Adding "ATLAS_URI=" to my config.env fixed my TypeError.